# Simple map<> instantiation, I can't compile, please help

Tags: c++

Why I can't compile this code?

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class MyTest {
    template<typename T> void test() const;
};
template<typename T> void MyTest::test() const {
    map<string, T*> m;
    map<string, T*>::const_iterator i = m.begin();
}
```

My compiler says:

```
In member function ‘void MyTest::test() const’:
test.cpp:8: error: expected `;' before ‘i’
```

What is it about? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a dependent name, you need to append `typename` to the const_iterator because its type depends on the type of `T`.

```
template<typename T> void MyTest::test() const {
    map<string, T*> m;
    typename map<string, T*>::const_iterator i = m.begin();
}
```

[C++ faq on depenent names](http://womble.decadentplace.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation)